# Updating the styling of a WPF DataGrid and forcing a refresh

Tags: wpf, datagrid, refresh

I'm using an IValueConverter in conjunction with DataTriggers (all in code, not XAML) to implement conditional styling for a WPF DataGrid (from codeplex.com).  I have all the code in place, but when I update the styling (after obtaining some values from form elements) the datagrid does not update the display of the elements.  I have to manually call `this.dataGrid.InvalidateVisual()` and then scroll down and back up to get the grid elements to refresh themselves.  Is there a better way of doing things ?

I've tried using `this.dataGrid.Items.Refresh()`, but this causes a rebinding of the grid data (of which there may be thousands of rows) which in turn causes a huge jump in my program's memory consumption.  Does anybody have any idea how to manually force a redrawing of the WPF data grid ? I've also tried doing `this.dataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {}));` to try to force the dispatcher to perform an operation that will result in a redraw, but to no effect.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of styling requires that the style gets updated??? Have you looked at triggers, value converters?

Comment: I have a view that gets an updated DataContext.  I'm implementing a log viewer that's supposed to be capable of displaying thousands of records for our technicians out in the field.  They have to be able to query the various fields and automatically have cells with out-of-range values highlighted for them so they can make adjustments to physical equipment. I'm already using triggers and a value converter in code to implement this, the only thing is that the WPFToolKit DataGrid doesn't properly update.  Other controls do, but not this.